# CSS not loading on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone

I’ve been working on this site for a week or so, but a couple days ago, the site stopped loading the CSS on iPhones. It works great on android or google. Look for CSS/HTML/PHP errors & found none that fixed the problem. I’ve tried a few things I’ve found on the internet but no luck. Does anybody see anything wrong with the code that could be the problem?

Here’s the site: www.ordershack.com

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your site on my Iphone 12.4 on Safari Browser and it seems to have loaded up. What css issues are you having?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgrPT.jpg

Here is a screenshot from my Iphone.